# How to use font-awesome with node + express framework

Tags: css, node.js, express, fontawesome-4.4.0

Without less file is there any chance to use font-awesome in node with express framework 
Please help
Thank You

Comment: Definitely you can.

Comment: Sorry i am asking how can i use without less file, Please let me know @CuriousMind

Comment: app.use(express.static('public')); for serving static files link for reference ... https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Use a CDN I guess, then u don't have to download a new file in your server https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/fontawesome/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the public directory and include the font-awesome library.

`/* Public static directory */
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

So your **app structure** should be something like this,

`public/
    vendor/
       font-awesome-4.7.0/
         css/
         js/ ..etc`

In your **html** file include as usual

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Is this not considered bad practice since it exposes your file structure in the html file?

Comment: No. Everything on the client is visible to the user. They can access your assets, just codes etc. If you don't make these as public they won't be accessible by the browser.